# How to predict the probability label of each word in sentence using a classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, classification, data-science

I am trying to predict each label of word from review sentences. By far I have trained a classifier before with training data and now I am using on testing data. Basically, what I want to achieve is that from a full sentence the first word is removed, predict the rest of the sentence label, next return the first word and remove the second, predict again so on. This procedure would remove **i-th** word and predict rest of sentence label in every case.

I ran following code which is capable to remove one word and then return it back, but the problem is that my classifier predicts the whole sentence, because I use stems1 pre-process it list as whole document, thus I thought I could use i loop instead of stems1 at `fit_transform` but does not work.

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=identity_tokenizer,use_idf = True, lowercase = False, max_features = 401) 

X_new = vec.fit_transform(stems1).toarray() #stems1 is a pre-processed list that contains inside reviews lists

 from typing import List                                                                             
 for i in stems1: 
      for j in range(0,len(i)):                                                            
          i.pop(int(j)                                                                            
            new_pred = m.predict_proba(X_new)[:, 0]                                  
          i.insert(j, a)
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by "sentence" label. But then you say word label as well. So which is it? Can you give an example of what you mean by that?

Comment: Ok I will give a simple example:   **This game is amazing.       1**                                             The sentence I mean is one of the text reviews  and 1 or 0 values is the sentiment label(recommended/not recommended) turned to binary representation.  I already have created this classifier model which predicts the sentiment label in a training dataset. I want now to predict from a testing dataset the sentiment label of text every time I remove the i-th word of it in this pattern: "game is amazing"  "this is amazing".